# How to auto adjust wrapper height when padding is applied to inner elements

Tags: css

Allow me first to mentionne that I know how to adjust height in normal scenarios. Nevertheless I am confronted to something tricky for me right now,  and I did not found solutions in other posts.

I have a div called "header" taking the full width of the page.
Inside that div there is a div called "wrapper". It is centered using margin.
Inside that wrapper there is a logo floating on the left and a menu floating on the right.
The first two div (header and wrapper) are suppose to auto adjust their heights according to the content (logo and menu). To do this I added a "clearer" div after my floating divs. It is working fine except when i put some padding to the li elements of my menu. In that case the div do not adjust. See the blue li in the fiddle here below. Hope to be clear and hope someone can help. Thank you.

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/Gynft/

HTML :

```
  <div id="header">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="logo">
                [ logo ]
            </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="" class="">AGENDA</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="">MESSAGERIE</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="">COMMUNAUTEE</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="">DECONNEXION</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>​
```

CSS :

```
body {
font-family:arial;
font-size:10px;
}

.clearer {
clear:both;
}

#header{
background:yellow;

}

#wrapper {
background:green;
width:560px;
margin:20px auto;
}

#logo {
background:purple;
float:left;
}

#menu {
background:orange;
float:right;
}

#menu li {
display:inline;
padding:5px 10px;
background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure why exactly this is fixing your problem, but changing the blue li's `display` to `inline-block` instead of just inline seems to work!

Comment: thank you very much Stephan ! working like a charm :) i will take this as the answer to my problem

Comment: @Marc i thing it's should be overflow:hidden because you are using floating . If you are using floating div than clear to your parents div according to Shailender_Arora's answer....

Comment: The floating is not causing the problem. The display: inline with padding attached to it is.

Comment: the thing is that Stephan's proposition works, whether the one proposed by Shailender is causing some side effects. Check the comment i made to his post if you like...

Answer (score 0):

Hey Marc its simple you can get your desired results throught : `overflow:hidden;`

its because you didn't clear your `parent div` and you have used `floating` in your `child div` so i have `cleared` your `parent div` with `overflow:hidden;` and now its working fine as per your requirement.

And i hope you are looking like this........

**CSS**

```
#header, #wrapper {
overflow:hidden;
}

#header{
background:yellow;
}

#wrapper {
background:green;
width:560px;
margin:20px auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gynft/5/)

Comment: hello Shailender. thanks for trying to help. unfortunately with your proposition the padding property is not working normally anymore (padding:50px 10px;) The vertical paading is not taken in consideration. Strangely when I just use padding:10px it is working. But I need a different horizontal and vertical padding, so i can't go with your proposition. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#wrapper {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
     margin: 20px auto; overflow: hidden;
     width: 560px;
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly next time, please. I reformatted it this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background:#ededed;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            .main{
                width:720px;
                border:1px solid red;
                padding:5px;
            }
            .menu-item {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 0;
            }
            .menu-item li{
                display: table-cell;
                width: 1%;
                float: none;
                border:1px solid green;
                margin:2px;
                padding:10px;
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="main">
                <ul class="menu-item">
                    <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu item 5</a></li>
                </ul>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```